# Which Songs and Parts of the Musical Score for Pete's Dragon are Anachronistic?

Tags: soundtrack, petes-dragon-1977

I've heard somewhere that the Songs and Musical Score for the 1977 Disney Film "Pete's Dragon" are Anachronistic. But I don't know how? Which Songs and Parts of the Musical Score are Anachronistic?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a source for this idea?

Comment: [The film's musical score and songs are considered to be anachronistic and out of place for the time and setting of the film where shanties and other period music would have more authenticity. This is because both producers and song writers agreed that the modern pop vocal style of Helen Reddy would make the film far more appealing to a broad audience.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076538/trivia)